# How to load a piece of script inside jquery overlay?

Tags: jquery, load, overlay, external

I am using this http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/external.html to open an overlay which loads an external page which in it, it has php code to populate that page. My problem comes when I try to run this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
                    $("#thumb1").mouseover(function() {
                        $("#main_picture_content").attr("src","images/p79_wg_amethyst_bezel_2.jpg");
                        $(this).mouseout(function() {
                            $("#main_picture_content").attr("src","images/p79_wg_amethyst_bezel_1.jpg");
                        });
                    });
                </script>
```

inside that page (inside the overlay). Those image sources are loaded when the overlay is loaded. The script is not working though. My guess is that it is not loading. I read around and $getscript was mentioned a ot, but no real solution yet. Any help?

Comment: Oh oh oh, SCRIPT.  I read that wrong :/

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery functions for `thumb1` and `main_picture_content` are not active for the page loaded inside the overlay because that overlay (and the elements in it) does not exist when your js/jquery is initially loaded.

You need to use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to activate existing elements now and in the future. Try something like (untested):

```
$("#thumb1").live('mouseover', function() {
                        ...
                    });
```

And place this in the parent js file

Comment: The parent page where you are loading the overlay from

Comment: yeah but the problem is the source of those images are received when the page inside the overlay loads.

Comment: doesn't matter - changing the img src is just the result of the jquery functions. The problem is that your functions have to use the live() or bind() so that the jquery code will still work even though the elements don't exist until the overlay does